# Can I split an array out of function parameters

Tags: python, arrays, python-2.7

Given a fixed length list and a function

```
l = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
def printMiddle(first, middle, last):
    print middle
printMiddle(*l)
```

How do I force middle to `print l[1:3]` with the output below?

```
[2, 3, 4]
```

Comment: what u r passing to printMiddle function??

Comment: What is the expected output? Please give examples of input-output.

Comment: Added finction call and output inline

Comment: Be more clear on your Question...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do:

```
l = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

def printMiddle(*args):
    print(args[1:-1])

printMiddle(*l)
```

The asterisk `*` makes `args` a tuple of the positional arguments (parameters, as you have it) to the function. `[1:-1]` takes a slice of all but the first and last items in the tuple.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
l = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
def printMiddle(lst,first, last):
    print lst[first:last]
printMiddle(l,1,4)
```

Although It would be much sensible to do like this:

```
l = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
print l[1:4]
```